# Alpha Pagination

Tags: php, sql, database, pagination, alpha

I am attempting to implement pagination based on the surname in a MySQL database. The entries are saved as "Firstname Lastname" and I would like to display the results based on the first letter of the surname, and if there are a lot of results for that letter, to split that list up into numerical pages. Any help at all is appreciated!

Comment: This is a pretty broad request on a very well-covered topic. Do you have any specific questions? Also, when you say "Firstname Lastname", do you mean that it's in a single column in your database that way? If so it's going to make things MUCH more difficult because your database is not properly designed.

Comment: How exactly would you go about it? I found a few script examples, but they were based on numerical pages, not ordered by letters. And yes unfortunately it's in a single column.

Answer (score 1):

You say, `And yes unfortunately it's in a single column.` This is going to make it both difficult and error-prone to do what you're asking for. After all, keeping away from real SQL code for the moment, how are you going to specify the rule for how to identify the start of the surname?

Do you say "everything after the first word is the surname"? `Cathy Anne Phillips` breaks your rule. Do you say "only the last word is the surname"? `Samuel Reeves Montgomery` breaks it. You can't write a good algorithm to recognise where the given name ends and the surname begins.

If you want to do this, the first step is to change the database table format so that surname and firstname are in different columns.

Comment: Names will only be first and last name, so in the case of your examples it would only be "Cathy Phillips" or "Samuel Montgomery". Also, I don't know enough to change the database design - it was made for me.